# Constrained optimization using Lagrange multipliers - Unbounded functions

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I was trying to find the min/max for 
f(x,y) = x^3 + y^3
Subject to g(x,y) = xy = 4 .

Using Lagrange multipliers & partial derivatives.
< 3x^2 , 3y^2 >  = k< y ,x>

Solving these two + xy = 4, gives k = 6 , x = +-2 , y = +-2
This gives a max of 16 & min of -16 for f(x,y).

However these are obviously not the max, min.
Basically the max, min are unbounded.
So what am I missing here ?
When is there a finite max, min for f(x,y) constrained by g(x,y) = c

Comment: The function is unbounded above and below on the feasible set. Hence at best you can find the local $\max,\min$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuous image of a compact set is compact. A subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded. Unfortunately, these facts will not help much here because we're interested in the hehaviour of a conttinuous function on an hyperbola, which is closed but not bounded. It is certainly possible that a coninuous function might attain a maximum or a minimum on an unbounded set but there is no guarantee that that will happen and it does not happen in this case.